# 2 receiver call using single alarm manager object

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have two Broadcast Receivers :

1. Sending SMS.
2. Manage notification.

I have to call both receivers at a specified time.

How can i do that?? is it possible?

The code for calling notification alarm is given below:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,specialNotification.class);
        Bundle bu=new Bundle();
        bu.putString("TITLE", title);
        bu.putString("BODY", body);
        bu.putInt("ICON", icon);
        bu.putLong("TIME", t);
        intent.putExtras(bu);
        //Toast.makeText(context, ""+_id, 3000).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "REpeat Alarm", 3000).show();
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, _id, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t, MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR, pi);
```

Please help me to call SMS receiver

Thanks in advance..

Comment: May i know why you want to call two receiver?

Comment: in my app, there is two check boxes, for notification and for send sms.. if both are selected, i hav to do both simultaneously, otherwise seperately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can create a new `Intent` for your SMS broadcast receiver, and `PendingIntent`, passing it a different id value than the one you passed to the `PendingIntent` of your notification.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context,specialNotification.class);
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(context,Your_SMS_Receiver.class);

Bundle bu=new Bundle();
bu.putString("TITLE", title);
bu.putString("BODY", body);
bu.putInt("ICON", icon);
bu.putLong("TIME", t);
intent.putExtras(bu);

PendingIntent notifPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, NOTIFICATION_ID, notifIntent, 0);
PendingIntent smsPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, SMS_ID, smsIntent, 0);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t, MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR, notifPI);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t, MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR, smsPI);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the two reciver by calling the SMS recivers and from the SMS reciver you can create a notification.